# Making a read/write function for UML files

Tags: c#

I'm working on an UML software/editor where a user can create a class diagram. However, I want to implement a function that saves and a function that can load an existing UML file. What I can do now is opening/saving a file with text which is written in a textbox in the application I've made:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GemDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(GemDialog.FileName, textBox.Text);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LoadDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StiLabel.Text = LoadDialog.FileName;
                textBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(StiLabel.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can implement a function that can save it in .jpg, but that's not what I want to do. I just want to make it possible for the user to save his work and then open it again.

Answer (score 0):

It would require some more efforts to do it right. Use properties and [XmlAttribute] to tag them (otherwise, all public properties will be serialized by default). Then you can serialize all that stuff into XML which is a good option for saving settings/configuration, whatsoever:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UMLModel));
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("c:\myUML.xml",FileMode.Open);
```

Make sure the file exists before saving or you create it with SaveFileDialog.
Where UMLModel is your class which holds all the data you need to save. Please [read](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/436/how-to-read-and-write-xml-in-c-sharp) as starting point.